# Chaining models together Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I have three models:

Challenge

User

Entrant

Challenge just has its primary key

User just has its primary key

and Entrant has a foreign keys challenge_id and user_id

If I am querying from challenge (I have the challenge id) what is the best way with eloquent to get all of the users associated to that challenge? I essentially want an aggregate of all of the entrant data combine with all of the user data. I've been looking into the method hasManyThrough (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: This is actually a `belongsToMany` where `entrant` would be your pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you're looking for is:

```
Entrant::where('challenge_id', $challengeId)->with('users')->get();
```

The key to this piece of code is the `with` part, which [eagerly loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the users that are associated with each entrant. This method of loading related data solves the N+1 problem and results in reduced load on the database.

This code assume that you have set up the appropriate relationships between each of your eloquent models...

```
User      hasMany   Entrant
Challenge hasMany   Entrant
Entrant   belongsTo User
Entrant   belongsTo Challenge
```

Comment: Thats awesome, thanks for the little extra explanation, going to eager load whenever I can.